# rake db:create the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

give me solution for this 
when i'm running  rake db:create
it is showing warning like these

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from <class:Engine> at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/spree_paypal_express-073f2f814dd8/lib/spree_paypal_express.rb:5)
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Soletronspree::Application#task called at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
    at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/deface-0.5.2a/tasks/deface.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
soletronspree_test already exists
soletronspree_development already exists
```

Comment: I mean, what have you tried to resolve this problem?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Not getting idea how to solve that it is showing the error in library files.....

Comment: It prints you several recommendations. Did you follow them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try updating your gems, specifically spree_paypal_express.

```
bundle update
```

It is currently locked at 073f2f814dd8... and according to GitHub that SHA1 hash points to a 6 months old commit.

If you are currently not using the latest from the git repository, try them out by changing the gem line to this:

```
gem "spree_paypal_express", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_paypal_express.git"
```

The latest paypal extension release depends on Spree 1.0.0 or later. To install 1.0.0 change your current spree gem line to this:

```
gem 'spree', '1.0.0'
```

and run `bundle update`

Keep in mind, that updating Spree may break previous functionality elsewhere.
But it's always a great idea to stay up-to-date to have all the newest features.

Comment: ya updated but same error when i'm trying the  rake db:create or rake db:migrate commands

Comment: Try posting your new error, it should differ from the one you had before. If the gem in fact is updated.

Comment: when i'm trying for bundle install that time it is showing like this


Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_paypal_express (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (>= 1.0.0) ruby

    spree (= 0.60.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      spree_core (0.60.0)

Comment: Update your spree gems altogether. The latest stable release is 1.0.0 and you are using 0.6.

Updated my answer to install those.